# ¿Cómo evitar refrescamiento al realizar animaciones con WinFormAnimation?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, animación, picturebox

Investigando un poco encontré en GitHub una librería ([WinFormAnimation](https://github.com/falahati/WinFormAnimation)) que me permitía lo que deseaba y luego de probarla me pareció genial.

El problema comenzó cuando decidí realizar una animación donde una imagen que estaba oculta detras de otra, realizaba un movimiento en diagonal hacia afuera; para posicionarse en la esquina superior derecha de la primera, cuando se hacia click sobre esta, y hacia el movimiento inverso cuando daba otro clic en la primera. El efecto no fue el deseado ya que la segunda imagen entraba en un proceso de pestañeo algo molesto.

Deberia verse de esta manera:

[image: Esta imagen es como normalmente debe verse]

Sin embargo asi es como se ve algunas veces:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte de la segunda imagen (el circulo con los 3 puntos), que esta mas proxima al telefono, produce un efecto que simula como un redibujado de un cuadrado blanco en la zona en la que ésta se encuentra.

Aqui les dejo el codigo que usé.

```
    private void device_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        //closeBtn es la imagen que representa el circulo con los 3 puntos
        closeBtn.SendToBack();
        //Obtengo el control sobre el cual se hizo click           
        PictureBox device = (sender as PictureBox);
        //Posiciono inicialmente la imagen en el mismo medio de la del telefono pera detras
        closeBtn.Location = new Point((device.Left + device.Width / 2)-(closeBtn.Width/2), (device.Top+device.Height/2)-(closeBtn.Width / 2));
        //pongo visible la imagen del circulo pk inicialmente esta oculta
        //Por cierto esta linea no influye en el problema pk la kito y siga dando lo mismo
        closeBtn.Show();
        //Creo la animación
        Animator2D anim = new Animator2D(new Path2D(new Float2D(closeBtn.Left , closeBtn.Top), new Float2D(device.Left+device.Width, device.Top-14), 100, AnimationFunctions.CubicEaseOut));
        //Inicio la Animación
        anim.Play(closeBtn, Animator2D.KnownProperties.Location);
     }
```

Por cierto el mismo ejemplo lo usé pero reemplazando la segunda imagen por un botón y todo perfectamente, no pestañó nada, ni la imagen, ni el botón, ni se dibujó el molesto rectángulo de fondo blanco.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema no es la librería de animación, en WindowsForm la optimización es muy limitada y utilizar características como animaciones no ofrecen el resultado esperado.
Para poder evitar el parpadeo en los controles puede utilizar la caracteristica de **DoubleBuffer** combinado con los métodos **SuspendLayout** y **ResumeLayout** de esta manera:

```
//Contenedor de los Pictureboxs
public Form1()
{  
    //En el constructor del formulario habilite la opción DoubleBuffer
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.SetStyle(
        ControlStyles.UserPaint |
        ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
        ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);

    //Habilita la opción a los controles que ejecutan la animación
    EnableDoubleBuffered(miPicturebox1, true);
}

private void device_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    this.SuspendLayout(); //<---

    closeBtn.SendToBack();         
    PictureBox device = (sender as PictureBox);
    closeBtn.Location = new Point((device.Left + device.Width / 2)-(closeBtn.Width/2), (device.Top+device.Height/2)-(closeBtn.Width / 2));
    closeBtn.Show();

    this.ResumeLayout(); //<---

    Animator2D anim = new Animator2D(new Path2D(new Float2D(closeBtn.Left , closeBtn.Top), new Float2D(device.Left+device.Width, device.Top-14), 100, AnimationFunctions.CubicEaseOut));
    anim.Play(closeBtn, Animator2D.KnownProperties.Location);
}

public static void EnableDoubleBuffered(Control control, bool enable)
{
    Type controlType = control.GetType();
    PropertyInfo pi = controlType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", 
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    pi.SetValue(control, enable, null);
}
```

Comment: Hice exactamente lo ke me comentastes y todavía sigo viendo el fondo blanco del efecto de pestañeo.

Comment: Supongo que ambos Pictureboxs (tanto el que contiene la imagen del teléfono celular, como así también la que contiene el circulo con los 3 puntos) contienen fondo transparente y que el fondo que se ve color verde gradiente debe ser una imagen alojada como fondo del formulario contenedor. Si esto es así los Pictureboxs al moverse deben re dibujar ese fondo verde ya que no soportan transparencia real, a modo de prueba quite esa imagen gradiente y haga una prueba. si este es el problema debe reducir el tamaño de esa imagen  o dibujar el gradiente directamente al formulario.

Comment: Ok probare y luego le cuento si pude resolver. Saludos